# ASP.NET Web API not returning XML

Tags: c#, xml, json, post, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller and method that adds user to a DB.

I call it from Fiddler with a Request Header as follows -

> Content-Type: application/xml
>
> Accept: application/xml
>
> Host: localhost:62236
>
> Content-Length: 39

And a request body of -

```
<User>
  <Firstname>John</Firstname>
  <Lastname>Doe</Lastname>
</User>
```

This works as expected, the method is called, the user object processed in the method PostUser.

```
 public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage PostUser(User user)
        {
            // Add user to DB
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
            var relativePath = "/api/user/" + user.UserID;
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, relativePath);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

I am performing my Model Validation in it's own class

```
public class ModelValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            // Return the validation errors in the response body.
            var errors = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> keyValue in actionContext.ModelState)
            {
                errors[keyValue.Key] = keyValue.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage);
            }

            actionContext.Response =
                actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors);
        }
    }
}
```

BUT if I post the following

```
<User>
  <Firstname></Firstname> **//MISSING FIRST NAME**
  <Lastname>Doe</Lastname>
</User>
```

The Model is invalid, and a JSON response is returned even though I stated Accept: application/xml.

If I perform model validation within the UserController, I get a proper XML response, but when I perform it in ModelValidationFilterAttribute I get JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problems with the following code:

```
var errors = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors);
```

So you try to create the response from the `errors` object where its type is `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();`.

Web.API will try to automatically find the right `MediaTypeFormatter` for your response type. However the default XML serializer (`DataContractSerializer`) not able to handle the type `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();` so it will use the JSON serializer for your response.

Actually you should use the [CreateErrorResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127078%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and just create the response from the `ModelState` directly (it will create a `HttpError` object which is XML seriazable)

```
public class ModelValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response =
                actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
                    actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's been driving me bonkers for the last hour, great answer, it's saved my sanity!

Comment: So if I have the Accept header application/xml, and have set UseXmlSerializer should this work with Request.CreateResponse or will it always try and use DataContractSerializer? It isn't working for me either way.

Comment: @GlacialSpoon the XmlSerializer also does not serialize Dictionaries, so you need to use a type which is Serialize-able.

Comment: @nemesv Thanks. Turns out that I had forgotten about XmlSerializer's need for parameter-less constructors on the model.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Web API will return JSON as its default type for responses outside of controller methods.

Have you tried disabling the JSON formatter, as suggested in this article?

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization

i.e.

```
void ConfigureApi(HttpConfiguration config)
{

    // Remove the JSON formatter
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
}
```